# How can I fill a matrix with random values that need to satisfy a condition?

Tags: r

I have following R-Code:

```
mat <- matrix(0L,500,10)


for(i in 1:500){
  mat[i,] <- rnorm(10,0,1) 
  
}
mat <- mat[mat[,10] >=-0.5,]

dim(mat)
```

I don't want to have values below -0.5 for my 10th column. However, I still want to have a matrix with 500 rows. Therefore I have to loop over my for-loop until dim(mat)[1] = 500. How can I do that?
Thanks for help!

Comment: a matrix is just a vector with dimensions. so you can fill the whole matrix at once: `mat[] = rnorm(prod(dim(mat)), 0, 1)` (or else just use this in the `matrix()` call directly

Comment: the rest of your question, I don't follow completely. could you explain more in words what you're after?

Comment: If you have enough memory I think an easier way t do this is to over-allocate the rows in the matrix and then remove. You know the probability tha `x < -0.5` so can estimate the number of rows as `500/(1-pnorm(-0.5)) ~=723`; by sampling you are unlikely to get exactly this number.  So you could choose a number a bit bigger and then remove any excess rows: `mat = matrix(rnorm(750*10), nc=10); mat <- mat[mat[,10] >=-0.5,]` if nrow(mat) > 500 just randomly remove the excess rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize the matrix in one step, without using a loop:

```
mat <- matrix(rnorm(500*10,0,1), 500, 10)
```

Then, using a while loop, replace the values below `-0.5` in the 10th column by sampling the normal distribution until all of them are greater or equal than `0.5`:

```
while (sum(mat[, 10] < -0.5)) { 
  mat[mat[, 10] < -0.5, 10] <- rnorm(sum(mat[, 10] < -0.5), 0, 1) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using base r you could try this approach.

First create a matrix, using random normal values across 500 rows and 10 columns:

```
mat <- matrix(rnorm(500, 0, 1), nrow = 500, ncol = 10)
```

Then remove values below -0.5 from the 10th column:

```
mat[which(mat[, 10] < -0.5), 10] <- NA
```

Replace NA with an alternative value as needed.

Comment: I recommend `rnorm(5000,0,1)` so every column contains different values.